# Modifying XLSX column datatype to Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, xlsx

Iam working on XLSX npm and trying to download a sample excel file and add some data to it and then upload it back. I have fields like `MOBILE NUMBER` , `DATE` , `TIME` , `NAME` .  When I upload the file Iam converting it to JSON and the values for the fields DATE , TIME and MOBILE NUMBER , I am receiving data in decimal and exponential values , so Iam trying to modify excel column datatype to `Text` by default while downloading the excel file using the following code

```
this.headers[0] = ['Name', 'Mobile','Time','Date']

const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.headers);
const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.headers);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);
for (var r = range.s.r; r <= range.e.r; r++) {
  for (var c = range.s.c; c <= range.e.c; c++) {
    var cellName = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: c, r: r });
  }
}

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
```

> **wb.Sheets['Sheet1']['B1'].z = 'Text';**
>
> **wb.Sheets['Sheet1']['C1'].z = 'Text';**
>
> **wb.Sheets['Sheet1']['D1'].z = 'Text';**

```
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Sample.xlsx');
```

Using the above code Iam not able to modify the colum datatype to `TEXT` and I donot have any idea that what Iam expecting is acheivable , Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `set number` as text when writing an `excel` please add :-

```
var fmt = '@'; 
then when you  pass fmt insted of 'Text' like this : 

wb.Sheets['Sheet1']['B1'].z = fmt;
```

please write me if it helps you.

Comment: @Swati i have number with thousand separator and i want to export to excel as a **Number** so how can i do for column?

Comment: @Swati i have posted new questing for that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154444/change-xlsx-column-datatype-to-number-in-angular-5