# change XLSX column datatype to number in Angular 5

Tags: excel, angular5, xlsx

1. i am using **xlsx** library for export to excel (**"xlsx": "0.16.1"**)
2. i have three columns with thousand separator number, so when i export that data then it will consider as a string, but i want number type, here is code of Export to Excel file

   ```
   public downloadExcel(json: any[], excelFileName: string, merges?: any): void {
       let worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet;
       if (merges) {
           worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(json);
           worksheet['!merges'] = merges;
       } else {
           worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
       }

       const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };

       var fmt = '0'; 
       workbook.Sheets['data']['C2'].z = fmt;

       const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
       this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
   }

   private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
       const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
           type: 'application/octet-stream'
       });
       FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + "_" + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + "_" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
   }
   ```

   [image]

> so i want to change **C,D,E,F** column data type, so i can directly SUM that column,

Answer (score 1):

Before generating Excel from JSON, modify JSON by removing Comma(,) from numbers and convert them into numbers like:

```
parseInt('10,340'.replace(/,/g, ''))
```

This way you will store the number without comma so Excel will consider that column as a number automatically.

Let me know if you have any questions.

------------EDIT------------

You can replace the comma(,) from the original number as shown above and use column formatting **#,##0.00**. This way it will display comma at every thousand points but actually it will store it as a number so you can do all arithmetic operations

Comment: but i want thousand separator as it is, without removing **comma** i want number datatype in Excel

Comment: You can replace the comma(,) from the original number as shown above and use column formatting #,##0.00. This way it will display comma at every thousand points but actually it will store it as a number so you can do all arithmetic operations.

Comment: could you give me one example.